# Which is a permanent ID?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Angular v12 using both Google and Azure Active Directory authentication.

After a successful login, Google's payload has a 21-digit `sub`, a permanent ID for the account. Looking at Azure's, which of the followings is the permanent ID?

- `uniqueId`, a 36-char string
- `account.homeAccountId`, value = `uniqueId`.<another 36-char>
- `account.localAccountId`, value = `uniqueId`
- `idTokenClaims.sub`, a 43-char string

This permanent ID should be unique among AAD including @outlook.com, @hotmail.com and etc. MSAL v2.1

Comment: I'm not sure if you have access to the user's claims anyway with Angular, but the claim type `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"` is supposed to be immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mxmissile, based on this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/claims), `.account.idTokenCalims.oid` (same value as `.uniqueId`) should be the what I'm looking for.